# How python redis client encode data before saving to redis

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

Using redis-py, I saved key-value to redis,for exp, 'gdf': 'gdfgdfgq' to redis. I could retrieve that the value by the key after that. But when I retrieved the value through redis-cli, I got "\x80\x02X\a\x00\x00\x00gdfgdfgq\x01.". What is this? Why I got an extra characters? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: How exactly did you use redis-py to store the value, and how did you use redis-cli to retrieve it? Normally, when you do `redis-cli get gdf` it should return the result in a human readable form when stdout is a terminal, and the raw value when it's something else (file or pipe).

Comment: Are you perhaps using the python pickle mechanism to encode the value?

Comment: Yeah, Pickle is what I am asking. redis client for python use Pickle to serialize/deserialize data by default I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That object has been pickled:

```
In [8]: import pickle

In [9]: pickle.loads(b"\x80\x02X\a\x00\x00\x00gdfgdfgq\x01.")
Out[9]: 'gdfgdfg'
```

redis-py doesn't serialize objects, so whatever code you used to store the string in redis pickled the object.

Comment: So I wanna read that data from Nodejs. So which node package should I install

Comment: @achilles don't pickle if you don't intend to process the data only with python. To access redis from node.js, just google for options.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Currently Im using redis-py. I guess that python-redis client using pickle to serialize data before transmit it. How can I change the setting

Comment: @achilles: redis-py does not handle any sort of serialization, it just stores strings. Can you post the code you're using to store the data in redis? Somewhere you're using `pickle`.